# How to exec a docker container in Visual Code?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

What I want is enter in the container and modify with visual code not with using Vim.
How can I do this? Is there some extension in visualCode?

The command I use to enter to the docker container :

```
docker exec -it "idContainer" /bin/bash
```

Comment: Please don't add "solved" or similar phrases to your question when you've solved the problem. If someone gave you an answer, [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). If you found a solution on your own, [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) (you can also accept your own answer after two days). Accepting answers is also the way to show a question has been solved - editing "solved" into the question is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a extension at visualCode that make what I want. The name of extension is "Docker Workspace" from IIBUN Toshiyuki very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Docker Explorer Extension (formulahendry.docker-explorer)

[image: Just right click on container then Execute in Bash]

Comment: This is not what I want, I already use this, what I want is open the folders and archives of that container in visualcode without using Vim, like you do 'code example.php'. I dont know if this is possible